# Getting an element of a json?

Tags: python, json

I have a json and I want to get a element of it by python. the json look like this:

```
{"$id":"1","Data":
[{"$id":"2","ArticleId":39511,"Title":"a","Order":39,"TotalCount":0},
{"$id":"3","ArticleId":345921,"Title":"a","Order":21,"TotalCount":0},
{"$id":"4","ArticleId":43289,"Title":"a","Order":18,"TotalCount":0},
{"$id":"5","ArticleId":39540,"Title":"a","Order":16,"TotalCount":0},
{"$id":"6","ArticleId":963167,"Title":"a","Order":15,"TotalCount":0},
{"$id":"7","ArticleId":519284,"Title":"a","Order":14,"TotalCount":0},
{"$id":"8","ArticleId":109699,"Title":"a","Order":13,"TotalCount":0},
{"$id":"9","ArticleId":43466,"Title":"a","Order":12,"TotalCount":0},
{"$id":"10","ArticleId":39510,"Title":"a","Order":10,"TotalCount":0},
{"$id":"11","ArticleId":43307,"Title":"a","Order":9,"TotalCount":0},
{"$id":"12","ArticleId":715048,"Title":"a","Order":9,"TotalCount":0},
{"$id":"13","ArticleId":133952,"Title":"a","Order":8,"TotalCount":0},
{"$id":"14","ArticleId":459712,"Title":"a","Order":8,"TotalCount":0},
{"$id":"15","ArticleId":11503,"Title":"a","Order":7,"TotalCount":0}],"TotalCount":
14,"Id":"0","IsSuccess":true,"Message":"OK","StatusCode":200,"ValidationMessages":
null,"Exception":null}
```

In python I use:

```
mydata = json.loads(response.text)
```

now I want to know how to use mydata to get the strings. I mean "a"

Comment: you want to extract `Title` attribute value?

Comment: mydata is a dictionary with $id, Data and some more fields. Data is a list of dictionaries in which you want the Title attribute. `titles = [ i['Title'] for i in mydata['Data'] ]` will get you the list of titles.

Comment: This looks like some mongo query output. If yes, you could extract only what you need at query time, using the aggregation pipeline, instead of parsing the entire data in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```
mydata = json.loads(response_text)
titles = [dct['Title'] for dct in mydata['Data']]
```

A good way to help figure things like this out is to first do something like this:

```
print(json.dumps(mydata, indent=4))
```

Which, in this case, results in something like this being displayed:

```
{
    "Exception": null,
    "$id": "1",
    "ValidationMessages": null,
    "IsSuccess": true,
    "TotalCount": 14,
    "Message": "OK",
    "Data": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "TotalCount": 0,
            "ArticleId": 39511,
            "Order": 39,
            "Title": "a"
        },
        {
            "$id": "3",
            "TotalCount": 0,
            "ArticleId": 345921,
            "Order": 21,
            "Title": "a"
        },
            ..., etc,
        {
            "$id": "15",
            "TotalCount": 0,
            "ArticleId": 11503,
            "Order": 7,
            "Title": "a"
        }
    ],
    "Id": "0",
    "StatusCode": 200
}
```

From that, it usually becomes relatively easy to determine what you need to do to access any part or parts of the object.